how to convert octal into binary
void octbin()
{   
    int i,o,a,r,b[10],j=0;
    printf("octal: ");
    scanf("%d",&o);
    for(i=0;o>0;i++)
    {   
        r=o%10;
        
        for(i=0;r>0;i++)
        {  
            printf("hehe");
            a=r%2;
            (r==0)?b[i+1]=0:(b[i]=a);
            r/=2;
            
        }
        o/=10;
        printf("%d",b[i]);
    }
    for (i=i-1;i<=0;i--)
    {
        printf("%d",b[i]);
    }
}

this code results in a segmentation fault. how do I reframe this without converting the octal into decimal and then into binary

(r==0)?b[i+1]=0:(b[i]=a); <== Don't be this smart!

Read the input into a string rather than a number. Then process it one character at a time.

%d reads decimal. Why not use %o to read an actual octal value? And always check what scanf returns.


Use descriptive names. 2. Use spaces. 3. Use a debugger. 4. Be clear, not terse.


Also remember that once the input is read (as decimal, octal or hexadecimal) it will always be stored in binary. No conversion needed, just iterate over all the bits and print them one by one.

Aside: use larger arrays. b[10] will just hold the digits of a large decimal value of the int, but not its octal or binary equivalent. A 32-bit int has, well, up to 32 bits.

Echoing @pmg, whoever is teaching you to write garbage code like (r==0)?b[i+1]=0:(b[i]=a); needs to be ignored.  That's unreadable and unmaintainable.

With C2X:
unsigned x;
scanf("%o", &x);
printf("%b", x);


Will C2X make it out of ISO before 2025, do you think?  At the moment (I checked at https://iso.org, search term 9899), it is still "under development", though it seems to be getting closer.  But the DIS was sent to ISO in late 2023 or early 2024 — it seems to be taking an inordinate time to finalize it.

@JonathanLeffler The technical part was done summer 2022. The rest is ISO/IEC bureaucracy from there. We really ought to stop using ISO/IEC standards, since that organization is useless for technology. In the time period since 2022, thousands of microcontrollers that were supposed to be programmed in C have been released. The gap between technology advances and ISO's dinosaur organization is clearly halting progress for mankind. It's beyond ironic how non-profit volunteers have implemented most of the proposed changes (there are lots!) in shorter time that it takes ISO to publish a document.

Try to keep it simple:

void printBinary(unsigned int n)
{
    if (n > 1)
    {
        // Recursive call to print the bits of n/2
        printBinary(n >> 1);
    }
    // Print the least significant bit
    putchar((n & 1) ? '1' : '0');
}

int main()
{
    int number;
    if(scanf("%o", &number) == 1)
    {
        printf("Binary representation of %o (Hex:%x, Dec:%d): ", number, number, number);
        printBinary(number);
        putchar('\n');
    }
    else
    {
        printf("scanf error try again\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

https://godbolt.org/z/5EKabqvoa


this code results in a segmentation fault.

why the segmentation fault in the code you provided currently occurs is that exceeding the bounds the array b[]. What you can try to convert into a 3-bit binary number for each octal digit.
#include <stdio.h>

void octbin() {   
    int o, r, b[32], i = 0, j;

    printf("octal: ");
    scanf("%d", &o);

    while (o > 0) {
        r = o % 10;
    
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            b[i++] = r % 2;
            r /= 2;
        }
    
        o /= 10;
    }

    printf("binary: ");
    for (i = i - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        printf("%d", b[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

